# Erlang server request order

Tags: erlang, server, client

I'm trying to understand request order in erlang, but I can't seem to grasp it very well. Here's the example code:

```
test() ->
    Server  = start(),
    spawn(fun() -> write(Server, 2),
                   io:format(”Child 1 read ~p~n”, [read(Server)]) end),
    write(Server, 3),
    write2(Server, 5),
    spawn(fun() -> write2(Server, 1),
                   io:format(”Child 2 read  ~p~n”, [read(Server)]) end),
    io:format(”Parent read ~p~n”, [read(Server)]).
```

And here's the server:

```
start() ->
    spawn(fun() -> init() end).

init() -> loop(0).

loop(N) ->
    receive
        {read, Pid} ->
            Pid ! {value, self(), N},
            loop(N);
        {write, Pid, M} ->
            Pid ! {write_reply, self()},
            loop(M);
        {write2, _Pid, M} -> loop(M)
    end.

read(Serv) ->
    Serv ! {read, self()},
    receive {value, Serv, N} -> N end.

write(Serv, N) ->
    Serv ! {write, self(), N},
    receive {write_reply, Serv} -> ok end.

write2(Serv, N) ->
    Serv ! {write2, self(), N},
    ok.
```

I understand that different values could be printed by the three different processes created in `test/0`, but I'm trying to figure out the lowest and highest values that could be printed by those `Parent`, `Child1` and `Child2` processes. The answer states:

- `Parent`: lowest 1, highest 5
- `Child1`: lowest 1, highest 5
- `Child2`: lowest 1, highest 2

Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that Erlang guarantees message order only from one process to another. If process A sequentially sends message 1 and then message 2 to process B, then B will receive them in that order. But Erlang guarantees no specific ordering of messages arriving at B if multiple concurrent processes are sending them. In this example, `Parent`, `Child1`, and `Child2` all run concurrently and all send messages concurrently to `Server`.

The `Parent` process performs the following sequential steps:

1. Spawns the `Server` process. This *eventually* sets the initial value in the `Server` loop to `0`.
2. Spawns `Child1`. This *eventually* writes the value `2` to `Server`, then reads from `Server` and prints the result.
3. Uses `write/2` to send the value `3` to `Server`. The `write` case in the `loop/1` function first replies to the caller and then installs the value `3` for its next iteration.
4. Uses `write2/2` to send `5` to `Server`. The `write2/2` function just sends a message to `Server` and does not await a reply. The `write2` case in the `loop/1` function just installs the value `5` for its next iteration.
5. Spawns `Child2`, which *eventually* calls `write2/2` with the value `1`, and then reads `Server` and prints the result.
6. Reads `Server` and prints the result.

For `Parent`, step 3 sends the value `3` to `Server`, so as far as `Parent` is concerned, `Server` now has the value `3`. In step 4, `Parent` calls `write2/2` to send `5` to the server, and that message must arrive at `Server` sometime after the message sent in step 3. In step 6, `Parent` performs a read, but all we know is that this message has to arrive at `Server` after the write message in step 4. This message ordering means the highest value `Parent` can see is `5`.

The lowest value `Parent` can see is `1` because if `Child2` gets its write message of `1` to `Server` after the `Parent` write message of `5` but before the final `Parent` read message, then `Parent` will see the `1`.

For `Child1`, the highest value it can see is `5` because it runs concurrently with `Parent` and the two messages sent by `Parent` could arrive at `Server` before its write message of `2`. The lowest `Child1` can see is `1` because the `Child2` write message of `1` can arrive before the `Child1` read message.

For `Child2`, the lowest value it can see is its own write of `1`. The highest value it can see is `2` from the write of `Child1` because the `Parent` writes of `3` and `5` occur before `Child2` is spawned, thus `Child1` is the only process writing concurrently and so only it has a chance of interleaving its write message between the `Child2` write and read messages.